# Excel Formula: how to split string by capital letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using a formula, not VBA, I would like to come up with a solution to split a string composed of multiple words. The formula should recognize the words where there is a capital letter and separate them. The result would be a string where the words are separated by ",".

To clarify this is an example of the string:

```
Nursing StudentStudentNurseNursing School

Desired Result:
Nursing Student,Student,Nurse,Nursing School
```

I am trying the following formula but I can only isolate the first word:

```
{=LEFT(Q4,SMALL(FIND(CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT("65:90"))),Q4&"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),2)-1)}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you need the workbook to be macro-free, you can always create another workbook that will do what you want in the original workbook, don't think you can solve the problem with a formula

Comment: Can't you go for the "Text to Columns" option? Is there any restrictions of using it?

Comment: How would you use "Text to Columns" to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You forgot to stipulate that words separated by a space should be counted as a single item.  At the moment you're asking for your result to be:  `Nursing ,Student,Student,Nurse,Nursing ,School`

Comment: I'm confused. You clearly stated in your question that you want "a formula, not VBA". But you accepted a VBA answer without further ado. How come the change of mind? If you are happy with a VBA solution, fine. But then don't say that you don't want VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need pure VBA. Create a custom Function to get in 1 cell the string you want. Then, use Text to Columns later if you need it.

My function:

```
Public Function GET_STRING(ByVal ThisCell As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer

Dim MyPositions As String
Dim ArrPositions As Variant

For i = 2 To Len(ThisCell.Value) Step 1
    If Mid(ThisCell.Value, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(ThisCell.Value, i, 1)) And _
    Mid(ThisCell.Value, i, 1) <> " " And Left(Mid(ThisCell.Value, i - 1, 1), 1) <> " " Then MyPositions = MyPositions & i & ";"
Next i

ArrPositions = Split(Left(MyPositions, Len(MyPositions) - 1), ";")

For i = 0 To UBound(ArrPositions) Step 1
    If i = 0 Then
        GET_STRING = Left(ThisCell.Value, ArrPositions(i) - 1) & "," & Mid(ThisCell.Value, ArrPositions(i), ArrPositions(i + 1) - ArrPositions(i))
    ElseIf i <> UBound(ArrPositions) Then
        GET_STRING = GET_STRING & "," & Mid(ThisCell.Value, ArrPositions(i), ArrPositions(i + 1) - ArrPositions(i))
    Else
        GET_STRING = GET_STRING & "," & Mid(ThisCell.Value, ArrPositions(i), Len(ThisCell.Value) - ArrPositions(i) + 1)
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

What I get when i use it on excel

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're pushing the envelope with this requirement. What you want to achieve requires looping over the same string repeatedly. That can only be done with recursion and Excel formulas don't do recursion.

With modern Excel 2016 you have Power Query (Get & Transform, or the add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013) and you can use that to write out the logic in M code if you don't want to use VBA. Power Query can be saved in a macro-free workbook and new data can be processed with the click of the "Refresh all" command in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

In B2:C28 fill in these :

```
A   ,A
B   ,B
C   ,C
D   ,D
E   ,E
F   ,F
G   ,G
H   ,H
I   ,I
J   ,J
K   ,K
L   ,L
M   ,M
N   ,N
O   ,O
P   ,P
Q   ,Q
R   ,R
S   ,S
T   ,T
U   ,U
V   ,V
W   ,W
X   ,X
Y   ,Y
Z   ,Z
 ,
```

Note: B28 =  , C28 =

then in A2 `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B2,C2)` then drag until A28,

in A29 `=RIGHT(A28,LEN(A28)-1)` Done.

Hope that helps. (:

+------[edit]-----+

or in one line :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Z",",Z"),"Y",",Y"),"X",",X"),"W",",W"),"V",",V"),"U",",U"),"T",",T"),"S",",S"),"R",",R"),"Q",",Q"),"P",",P"),"O",",O"),"N",",N"),"M",",M"),"L",",L"),"K",",K"),"J",",J"),"I",",I"),"H",",H"),"G",",G"),"F",",F"),"E",",E"),"D",",D"),"C",",C"),"B",",B"),"A",",A")," ,"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in access VBA
Pass a string like
?GET_SPLIT_STRING("SplitAtCapitals")
and get back the following
Split At Capitals

```
Public Function GET_SPLIT_STRING(xStr As String) As String
Dim i As Integer, xchar As String, ychar As String
ychar = UCase(Left(xStr, 1))
For i = 2 To Len(xStr) Step 1
    xchar = Mid(xStr, i, 1)

    If asc(xchar) = asc(UCase(xchar)) Then
        xchar = Space(1) & xchar
    End If
    ychar = ychar & xchar
Next
GET_SPLIT_STRING = ychar
```

End Function