# How to count in excel using two colums

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, excel-2007

I want to count like this:
Column 1 as a Range and Column 2 as criteria using simple excel form formulas.
Any suggestion!

Comment: Please share some of your sample data.. and what you had tried.. like these [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462803/formula-to-combine-similar-rows-but-sum-values-from-1-column/51462879) [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439093/excel-formula-how-to-split-string-by-capital-letters/51446616) [Example3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449555/excel-sumifs-checking-if-a-column-contains-text/51451498)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this :

```
  COUNTIF(range, criteria)
```

Range is column1 and criteria is column2.you can also click on formula to pass parameters with mouse clicks.

Comment: But how can i do this if i have a column with merged cells

Comment: thwn it depends on what are merged and what is their format.

Comment: @AbidAli if your cells are merged, you should probably mention that in your question. Please provide *all* relevant information. Showing a photo of some sample data will go a long way as well. Also, you should avoid merging cells at all costs as it leads to problems like this without much benefit.